# The number of partitions of $n$ to $k$ equal sized sets

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I want to calculate the number of partitions of $n$ into $k$ equal-sized sets with $k\ll n$.
I know that this is given by the multinomial coefficient ,$\left(\begin{array}{c}n \\ \frac{n}{k} \cdot \frac{n}{k} \cdots \frac{n}{k}\end{array}\right)$ but is there a way to evaluate this expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{n!}{k!\cdot (\frac nk !)^k}$$ is the answer. First, we permute all $n$ elements. Then, divide by $k!$ to account for the fact that all the subsets are indistinguishable (that is, it doesn’t matter in what order we create the subsets).

Finally, the order of the *elements* inside each subset doesn’t concern us, so divide by $(\frac nk !)^k$

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to be able to evaluate the expression in complexity sense. I know that the result is bounded from above by $k^n$ which is all the possible partitions without the equal size constraint (and with empty groups allowed), but is the real expression much smaller than that?

Comment: It is. You can verify that for $n=4, k=2$.

Answer (score 2):

\Well we generally do it in steps first $\frac{n}{k}$ from n and then $\frac{n}{k}$ from remaining n-$\frac{n}{k}$ and so on.

We get $(^n_\frac{n}{k})$.$(^{n-\frac{n}{k}}_\frac{n}{k})$....$(^\frac{n}{k}_\frac{n}{k})$

which gives your result, providing partitions are distinguishable or arranged.

In case partitions are not indistinguishable then you will need to divide the result with K! so it will then be $\frac{1}{k!}(^n_\frac{n}{k})$.$(^{n-\frac{n}{k}}_\frac{n}{k})$....$(^\frac{n}{k}_\frac{n}{k})$