# How many way to partition a set of n number into k subsets (empty subset is allowed)

Tags: integer-partitions, set-partition

I am working on finding the upper bound iterations of k-means algorithm. Many research show that the trivial upper bound is $O(k^n)$ since it can be shown that no clustering occurs twice during the course of the algorithm. So the upper bound can be calculated by counting the number of way to partition n points into k subset (empty subset is allowed). How to calculate this number? Why does it equal $k^n$?

For example:

Partition {1,2,3} into 2 subsets (n = 3, and k = 2)

1. Subset 1: {1,2,3} - Subset 2: {}
2. Subset 1: {1} - Subset 2: {2, 3}
3. Subset 1: {2} - Subset 2: {1, 3}
4. Subset 1: {3} - Subset 2: {1, 2}

Then multiply by 2! (swapping between subsets)

The total is 8 = $2^3$

Comment: Does this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3578443/the-number-of-partitions-of-n-to-k-equal-sized-sets/3578456#3578456

Comment: An upper bound of the number of partitions into $k$ sets is the number of maps $\{1,2,\dots,n\}\to\{1,2,\dots,k\},$ which is $n^k.$

Comment: To be clear, are the subsets labeled?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I don't find $n^k$ correct. I have provide an example in the question

Comment: @NhậtAnhVõNguyễn I didn’t say it was an exact value, I said it was an upper bound. That means $k^n\geq$ the number of such partitions.

Comment: I think the confusion in the comments was a result of @ThomasAndrews making a typo.  The number of maps $\{1,2,\dots,n\}\to\{1,2,\dots,k\}$ is $k^n$, not $n^k$.  The frustration arises from $n$ and $k$ meaning different things in different problems.  The end result is that the number of functions from $X$ to $Y$ is $|Y|^{|X|}$.  With the example you wrote, that answered my question about whether the subsets were labeled or not.  If they weren't labeled then you would have only had the $4$ outcomes you write and not multiplied by the $2$ there.

Comment: Whoops, yes, got them backwards. Should be $k^n$ is the upper bound, not $n^k$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It equals $k^n$ because each number can be put into any of the $k$ subsets.  You have $n$ numbers, so you multiply $n\ k$s together.  It would be harder if you didn't care about the order of the subsets because you might have more than one empty set.